# SGDClassifier - Why do I need to use argmax instead of argmin to find the lowest threshold satisfying given precision?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, numpy

I am an experienced programmer, but new to Python and data science. I am following Aurelien Gerone's book and I don't understand one thing.

I create SGDClassifier and calculate its precision_recall_curve(). Then I am trying to find the lowest threshold to satisfy precision equal to 90%:

```
precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_train, y_scores)
threshold_90_precision = thresholds[np.argmax(precisions >= 0.90)]
```

Why on earth I am searching for arg**max** if I need to find the minimum threshold value? If I try to use argmin I get the wrong value, with precision equal to 0.1.

As I understand this:

- precisions >= 0.90 creates an array with precision scores only above or equal to 0.90,
- argmax returns an index, at which I find the highest value in the given array (so this should be as far from 90% as possible, but it's not!),
- then I choose a threshold with returned index.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this myself.

precisions >= 0.90 doesn't create an array with precision scores only above 90%, but it transforms this array to the array of Booleans, where precisions below 90% are turned to False and the others are True.

argmax, if there are multiple identical, maximum values (and True is max here) returns **the first index** of this occurrence.

I sometimes hate this book, why he just doesn't use method like "array.first_equals(True)"?